# .bat file does not execute and the name of the file doesnt change

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to create a .bat file. What I do is the following:

1. Open a .txt file
2. Type "ECHO test".
3. Save it as "test.bat" with "all files" selected.

When I save it it does not say test however. I keep seeing "test.bat". And also the file doesn't execute when I hit it.

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here? Im running windows 10.

Comment: press `alt` . open `tools`->`folder options`->`view` an see if your extensions are hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are having folder settings to hide extensions as shown in here http://www.file-extensions.org/imgs/articles/4/366/windows-10-file-explorer-options.png. Reach there by `File - Change Folder and Search Options - View tab`  It should be `unchecked`.

The file you are seeing is actually "test.bat.txt". As you hide the extensions, you see "test.bat" only.

Just uncheck the box in the setting. And rename the file to "test.bat". That will fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try putting quotes around the filename and extension.

```
"filename.bat"
```

You have extensions hidden so notepad appends the hidden .txt to your file in the save as dialog if not enclosed in quotes.

See in Explorer - *File - Change Folder and Search Options - View tab*